# How to split an .RTF file into pages in .NET

Tags: .net, richtextbox

My input files have \page breaks in them and they also have a consistent footer on every page.  Simply chopping them at the \page isn't viable as the result won't be valid, the global data is needed in each document.

Another answer on here said to load it into a RichTextBox and then select the page of text.  All the various ways I've tried loading it have either resulted in what appears to be the file being treated as text rather than RTF, or the file not loading at all.

The docs on RichTextBox.LoadFile say the load will fail if the window handle isn't created--the module containing this doesn't even have a form to put the text box on.

Also, I may need to put some of the resulting files back together.  After they have been analyzed I may find two (or more) of them actually go to the same place and need to be combined.

Even more mysterious:  I added a RichTextBox to a form a few levels up (at -200, -200 so it doesn't actually draw anything), it has a handle--but still  fails to load the document.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve but you'll likely need a full RTF parser and then build the RTF from scratch using the various bits you parse out. If you're doing this in a DLL, using the RTF control is pretty much out of question.

Comment: @xxbbcc It's not actually a dll, just a data import routine with no user interface.  I could put a RichTextBox on another form and pass it in.  I actually am parsing it with the NRTFTree library, my attempts to build a new document with it made a mess (characters that didn't belong showing up in the output) but maybe I should go back to attacking it that way.